# how to improve performance of application on spark cluster?

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark

I have a 3 node cluster (1 master + 2 worker)

assigned driver-memory = 12gb

assigned executor-memory = 12gb

input data size = total 12gb (15 files, each of 800 mb)

Two files of 400 mb and 70 mb will be store in two Maps and broadcast to workers.
for each record from input data will lookup in broadcast-ed maps for match an will return a pairRDD ,say , JavaPairRdd < Object1, List< Object2 > > r1 .

From r1 i need two outputs,

first, i get it as r2 = r1.map(Output1Mapper())

for second, i need to output value List < Object2 > in the file named as key Object1 from r1.

hence i collect all keys in Set < Object1 > keys.

and for each Object1 in keys will lookup() in rdd r1 and the will output that List < Object2 > in output file.

Problem:

if i load all 15 files in a rdd then process as per above it fails with Error: JAVA HEAP SPACE, then i increase spark.driver.maxResultSize  to 3gb then again it fails.

i used another way, where i perform all above operations on each input files generate outputs , then it is taking 35 mins approx. on the cluster.

Need pointers on how to increase the performance and which approach will be best.

Comment: You need to profile your application to see what it is spending most of it's time doing and determine how you can change it to take less time and/or use less memory.

Comment: Is this cluster just for experimentation? If this is the production size, you should not use Spark. You're using at most 36 GB of memory. You could easily put that in a single machine and just process the data in Java without Spark. With so little resources you don't need a distributed computation framework.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i check that for second output it is taking around 90% of execution time.

Comment: @HarshalZope very good, can you narrow it down any further.